# How to implement the 'group' of alexnet in tensorlayer

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

group are used to group parameters of the convolution kernel (which connects the previous layer and the current layer) into k parts forcibly in alexnet, is there a simple implement for group in tensorlayer?

Comment: Are you talking about the way alexnet segregates the network into 2 parts and cross-feeds between them at the fully connected layers? That was done because they had access to 2 lower end GPUs (a number of years ago) that didn't have enough memory to fit the entire model on one of them, so they used that rather complex approach. These days you typically have GPUs that will fit the entire model in memory so that architecture isn't necessary, and you wouldn't want to use it.

Comment: You are right. But if I want to use the bvlc_alexnet pretrained model from imagenet, I think I should use the same network structure as bvlc_alexnet. That is why I want to use the 'group'.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://kratzert.github.io/2017/02/24/finetuning-alexnet-with-tensorflow.html) might be a useful link. You need to split the conv layers before convolving and then concatenate the result.

If it helps, the explanation of how the weights of [BVLC's alexnet](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet) in the model provided with Caffe are organized is given [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/ZkP84NcRv8I).

You will need to convert the caffemodel into a tensorflow-readable format (in my experience). Weights converted to .npy file are provided [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/tf_alexnet/) (bvlc_alexnet.npy) but it should be straightforward to convert it to your format of choice (for example, .h5).